# Unable to create new jupyter notebook. Getting error '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

Tags: anaconda

When trying to create new jupyter notebook. Following error is popping
'_xsrf' argument missing from POST[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55014094/230468

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably arose from having an open notebook idle for too long.

Try this:

Copy the changes you have made in that notebook, and restart Jupyter. 
Then reopen, paste your changes, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Check with another browser (or newer version of it). I started to get that error on Opera (might be an old version) but worked well using Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

for me restarting the kernel worked. Give it a try!

Comment: Try changing "In my case, restarting the kernel worked". Also, it might solve, but it most likely won't. So try searching for a better response