# '_xsrf' argument missing from POST - Need a Permanent Fix - Other Suggested Solutions are Not Working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

Every time I open Jupyter Lab from Anaconda, I receive the following error: `'_xsrf' argument missing from POST`.

I am using Google Chrome on Windows 10.

I've followed the suggestions from the other posts, e.g. copy and paste the URL into different Chrome tab and refresh the page.

It seems like my sessions are not properly closing, even if I terminate all kernels for that specific session.

I've closed all Jupyter Lab sessions by using `jupyter notebook stop <session_number>`. Nothing has changed.

Someone has suggested revising the configuration. However, I am unclear as to what problems a reconfiguration will cause downstream.

One last thing, I do **NOT** encounter this problem when running Jupyter Notebook. The error only occurs when I open Jupyter Lab.

Comment: Maybe some of the mentioned solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58019612) could be useful for you!