# '_xsrf' argument missing from POST when trying to create new notebook with jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have been unable to open a new notebook for a while now.  Have tried shutting down all kernels and even reinstalling jupyter lab but cant seem to fix it.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IA49.png)

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014094/jupyter-notebook-not-saving-xsrf-argument-missing-from-post ?

Comment: I have, no joy.

Answer (score -1):

Restart the kernel and try again! Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).